# Change item permissions using 2013 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, permissions, rest

I would like to create a 2013 workflow using Rest api call to break inheritance and change permissions on list items when they are created. This is in a Sharepoint Online environment.

Have anyone succeded to create such a workflow without using custom code ore downloading this solution: http://sp2013workflowactivities.codeplex.com/releases  ?

I would really like a description of such a workflow, I can't  for the life of me find any?

Comment: I found this to be the most straight-forward explanation of permissions setting in SPD 2013 workflows. I've not attempted it yet but was wondering if there is any documentation ANYWHERE that describes this at a dummies level? Book, URL forum, whatever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have done this before....for fun actually as a learning exercise in a SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow for SharePoint Online using the REST API.

I'm sure that you know, but you need to make use of the 'Call HTTP Web Service' action within an App Step.

Use this REST endpoint to break permissions on the item:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('YOUR LIST TITLE HERE')/items('YOUR ITEM ID HERE')/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=true,clearSubscopes=true)
```

Use this REST endpoint to assign permissions to a user:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('YOUR LIST TITLE HERE')/items('YOUR ITEM ID HERE')/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalId='ID OF USER TO ASSIGN PERMISSIONS TO',roleDefId='PERMISSION ID')
```

Within these endpoints, only replace the single-quoted words in CAPS with your values or workflow variables, which is what I did. These should be the REST endpoints that you need to be off on your way. If you need more help or clarification, please post in this thread. I will check it from time to time to see the outcome. Have a good one!

Here is a link to invaluable information on this subject, which is what I also used some time ago to accomplish this task:
 http://spsite.pro/Blog/Post/3/SharePoint-2013-REST-API-%E2%80%93-How-to-set-Unique-Permissions-%28Item-Level-Permissions%29

Comment: Very nice, thank you so much! 
Now i just need to get the permission ID and group ID. Is it possible to get thiese by title?

Comment: No problem. Sure, you can use `/_api/web/roledefinitions?$select=name,description,id` to get the permissions information and you can use `/_api/web/sitegroups` to get the information about groups. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Cool! I try to get the id by name, but nothing happens, do you see why? - This is what i use (Im new to rest api):
_api/web/roledefinitions/getbyname('contribute')?$select=id

Comment: Try this: `/_api/web/roledefinitions?$filter=Name eq 'Contribute'&$select=name,id,description'` for the permission ID and this `/_api/web/sitegroups?$filter=Title eq 'Owners'&$select=id` for the site group. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: When i use /_api/web/roledefinitions?$filter=Name eq 'Contribute'&$select=name,id,description  i get this respons:
{"odata.error":{"code":"-1, System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The given key was not present in the dictionary."}}}

Comment: But when i use this: https://skoleuniverset.sharepoint.com/sites/engelsk1/_api/web/roledefinitions/getbyname('Contribute')/id?
I get the this return:
{"odata.metadata":"https:\/\/skoleuniverset.sharepoint.com\/sites\/engelsk1\/_api\/$metadata#Edm.Int32","value":1073741827}
However it doesnt return the id in the variable i am using later to set the permission on the group? 
Thank you very much :)

Comment: Just to be sure, are you using the 'Get item from dictionary' action to store the ID from the response content of the 'Call HTTP Web Service' action? In the case of https://skoleuniverset.sharepoint.com/sites/engelsk1/_api/web/roledefinitions/getbyname('Contribute')/id, you would store that in a variable with the 'Get item from dictionary' action with the 'item by name or path' being 'd/Id' without the single quotes.

Comment: No im not, so thats probably it. My workflow basicly consists of 5 Call HTTP Web service action: 1. to get the role Id, 2. to get the group id, 3. to break permissions on item, 4. to give user in created by column permission, 5. to give the group permission. 
So should i use the Get item from dictionary action after 1. and 2. ? And when should i use the Build dictionary action? 
- like i said i am new to this :)

Comment: Ok, so the 'Build Dictionary' action is not needed at this point because the ResponseContent in the 'Call HTTP Web Service' action already stores the returned values in a dictionary. So, just set that default value of 'response' to a variable of your choosing to store the response. Then use the 'Get item from dictionary' action after 1 and 2. Set the 'from' to the dictionary in the HTTP Web Service call action that you set.

Comment: Also, in order to get these JSON results, you also need to build a dictionary for the request headers for the HTTP Web Service call. Build a dictionary and name it something like 'JSONRequestHeaders'. This variable needs to be one of the very first things that you set in your workflow. I have made some WFs in the past where I accidentally inserted HTTP Web Service calls before the request headers were set and that of course threw tons of errors. Follow this: http://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/

Comment: Now it works, thank you very much! And now to the last thing: I would like to be able to save this workflow as a template and implement it on a different site. This without having to edit the https://spsite.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename... part every time. Is it somehow possible to replace everything before /_api.. with a lookup ore something else?

Comment: Glad to hear it. I'm not really sure about using the workflow as a template to be honest. Off the top of my head, I don't know how to go about doing that in the best manner. However, that has given me something to think about! Can you mark my response as the answer to the question if you feel that it was sufficient?

Comment: Yes of course, thank you! And if you come up with something please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

using account which belongs to Site Members, I tried the above **REST API** to break the newly created list item by using its **BdcIdentity**, returned from successful **REST POST** I got this result:

```
{"d":{"BreakRoleInheritance":null}}
```

my code: `/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('ListName')/GetItemByStringId('__xxxxxxxxxxxx')/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=false,clearSubscopes=true)`

The **POST** was successful but if I open the list via *Lists/ListName* using a different account which is a site member also, I can still see the item created by the first account. I appreciate your thoughts on this.